# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User' getting this error

Tags: angular, typescript

While executing this I am expecting my form to display in Browser, not sure where I am going wrong. It's showing error like

```
    Error: src/app/addproducts/addproducts.component.html:18:48 - error TS2339: Property 'price' does not exist on type 'ADDPRODUCTSComponent'.
    
    18     <input type="text" id="price" [(ngModel)]="price" #client="ngModel" name="price" placeholder="Enter Price..">
                                                      ~~~~~
    
      src/app/addproducts/addproducts.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './addproducts.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component ADDPRODUCTSComponent.
    
    
    Error: src/app/addproducts/addproducts.component.html:18:48 - error TS2339: Property 'price' does not exist on type 'ADDPRODUCTSComponent'.
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component ADDPRODUCTSComponent.
```

user.ts

```
export class User{

    constructor(
                name:string,
                price:number
                ){}
    
    }
```

addproducts.component.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #client="ngModel" name="name" placeholder="Your Product name..">

    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input type="text" id="price" [(ngModel)]="user.price" #client="ngModel" name="price" placeholder="Enter Price..">

   

  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="registerNow()">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

addproducts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductDetailsService } from '../product-details.service';
import {User} from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addproducts',
  templateUrl: './addproducts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addproducts.component.css']
})
export class ADDPRODUCTSComponent implements OnInit {


user:User = new User("",0);
message:any;

  constructor(private serivce:ProductDetailsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
public registerNow(){

  let res=this.serivce.doRegistration(this.user)

  res.subscribe((data)=>this.message=data)



}

}
```

app-routing.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ADDPRODUCTSComponent } from './addproducts/addproducts.component';
import { OperationComponent } from './operation/operation.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {path:"",redirectTo:"register",pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"register",component:ADDPRODUCTSComponent},
  {path:"operation", component:OperationComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

product-details.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductDetailsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public doRegistration(user){

    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8084/add",user,{responseType:'text' as 'json'})
  }
}
```

Comment: Make variables in User as public. By default ts makes properties in constructor  as private, you need to mark them as public if you want so. Try `public string, public price:number` in constructor. + that what wrote Owen Kelvin in the answer :) as I see you changed a little the code before posting it

Comment: Try add `?` in model fields: `name?: string, price?: number`. And delete `name` attribute in inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not what you are doing wrong, its about what you have not done. Lets just pick the error as is

> Property 'price' does not exist on type 'ADDPRODUCTSComponent'

Now lets have a look at `ADDPRODUCTSComponent`

```
export class ADDPRODUCTSComponent implements OnInit {

  user:User = new User("",0);
  message:any;

  constructor(private serivce:ProductDetailsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
  public registerNow(){
    let res=this.serivce.doRegistration(this.user)
    res.subscribe((data)=>this.message=data)
  }
}
```

Does the component class contain `price`? When you bind to a property in the html then this property must be declared in the component class.

To solve the problem you simply need to add the property to the component

```
export class ADDPRODUCTSComponent implements OnInit {
  price: any;  // <---Added
  
  user:User = new User("",0);
  message:any;

  constructor(private serivce:ProductDetailsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
  public registerNow(){
    let res=this.serivce.doRegistration(this.user)
    res.subscribe((data)=>this.message=data)
  }
}
```